# Angular 5 - async pipe with firebase

Tags: html, angular

I want to add async pipe to angular firebase but i've got error that I don't know how to fix:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'AsyncPipe'

Firebase NoSQL database:

```
{
  "boss" : [ null, {
    "isPremium" : true,
    "name" : "John",
    "students" : 10000
  } ],
  "users" : [ null, "user", "user2" ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

**I've changed component code:**

```
user$: AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user$ = db.list("/users");
  }
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of user$ | async">
    {{ user }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm getting the same error... 
In Angular version 4 it works but, how to fix that in angular 5.2.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

The `async` pipe works with observables as argument. The error clearly states that `user$` field is not an observable.

Maybe you wanted to subscribe to the `valueChanges()` observable of the `db.object()`?

Take a look here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md

**UPDATE**

It seems that `AngularFireList<any>` is not an Observable, so you would receive the same error.

As I can see in the documentation of the **angularfire2**, the `list()` method returns an object in latest version, which has a `valueChanges()` method. Consider changing the code by calling the `valueChanges()` method and using the async pipe onto the resulting observable.

More details here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#50

Comment: with valuchanges method it works, but can u tell me, this var of type Observable subscribe and unscubscribe automatically with valuechanges method ?

Comment: The async pipe manages subscriptions automatically. The official documentation on async pipe has a good explanation: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because, `async` pipe works with Observables and the data you're returning is not.

You might want to change your code to this:

```
user$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user$ = db.list("/users").snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Or this:

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.user$ = db.list("/users").valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: The way is i need type AngularFireList<any> because on Observable i don't have later methods like: push, remove, udpate. You know how to fix that I will be able to use these methods later ?